# Error handling in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, jshint

I continue to receive these errors in JSHint - is it over concern?

```
Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'. — column 30
```

I've read that this is actually an efficient way of handling errors. What are your thoughts?

```
app.get("/users", function(req, res, next){

  User.find(function(err, users){

    // an error? get it out of here!
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    // no error? good. I'll do normal stuff here
    // res.render... etc.
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid this jshint error, you need to include those curly braces around your return statement. (I'm guessing your real code looks like `if (err) return next(err);` with no curly braces).

You can also add a trailing comment to the line like so to suppress the warning:

```
if (err) return next(err); // jshint ignore:line
```